# I am not able to see the changes of output when I try giving the input

Tags: javascript, input, onkeyup

I tried to give input but output is not showing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function my() {
        $str = document.getElementById("j").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $str;
        return $str;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <input type="text" name="j" id="j" onkeyup="my()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked that innerHTML is the right way to set the value of a text input type? Maybe try googling that as there could be another way to set the value of a text input

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.value` not `.innerHTML` for `<input />` tags:

```
$str = document.getElementById("j").value;
```

Here's a working snippet for you:

```js
function my() {
  $str = document.getElementById("j").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $str;
  return $str;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="text" name="j" id="j" onkeyup="my()" />
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview]